# How do i add plugins to a docker jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, plugins

while doing this, I would like to use a dockerfile to configure which plugins will be installed and then build it as a separate jenkins+plugin image.
How do I do so?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe Server fault or Super user comunities are best to ask this question, also, hope you find the answer

Answer (score 11):

There are two things about plugins one is preinstalled plugins and one is storing the installed plugins after jenkins is up. So for pre-installed plugins you will change your compose to below

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: jenkins
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
```

**.dockerignore**

```
jenkins_home
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

**plugins.txt**

```
cucumber-testresult-plugin:0.8.2
pam-auth:1.1
matrix-project:1.4.1
script-security:1.13
```

Now keep `jenkins_home` as volume mounted will make sure all your jenkin changes are persisted. Keeping a `plugins.txt` will make sure that your container starts with pre-installed plugins. And the volume mount will persist any of the shared plugin. A key point from documentation

> When jenkins container starts, it will check JENKINS_HOME has this reference content, and copy them there if required. It will not override such files, so if you upgraded some plugins from UI they won't be reverted on next start.

Please refer to this link if you need additional and latest information:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Is it possible to run the default jenkins image, install necessary plugins with the UI and commit the changes to the new docker image?

Comment: @IvanBalashov, that is what is happening the in the `Dockerfile` as well?

Comment: No,I was hoping to avoid manual editing of `Dockerfile`, but now I see that it doesn't get persisted because of volumes.

Comment: @IvanBalashov, it may be there in the file, but if you map the volumes, it will override the inside folder with a blank folder from host and hence whatever you added will not be there