# Can I commit the whole state of a docker container with "docker commit"?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

### Example 1

I have a running jenkins container for a while and installed a bunch of plugins. Also I have configured some build steps for my pipeline. Now I use `docker commit sd12418fsw mystuff/configuredjenkins:1.0`

#### Question:

Will the state of this container be copied to the new image? So if I push this image to another registry on another server and run a container out of the `configuredjenkins:1.0` image it will have the same state (configuration and plugins) it had as I commited it?

#### Example 2

I have a running ubuntu container. In this container I start using `apt-get install emacs` and started to create some directories for my microcontroller development environment. Since I love Arduino and Emacs - I want to combine both for a cool hackerman styled IDE to develop stuff in. I finished doing so and now have a nice development setup within my ubuntu container.

#### Question:

When I finished I'd love to have this setup **saved**. does running `docker commit jd234hac mystuff/mymicrocontrollersetup` give me an image which has all of the setup stuff in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answer is yes and no both. Any change that you make inside the container is part of commit. But if a volume was mapped, any modifications made that go into the container won't be saved as the state.

Also when you make changes, `docker history` won't show any details of these changes. This is not a good thing because then people using this image have no idea what was done in this layer which is committed.

Comment: I read about this `docker commit --change "ENV DEBUG true" c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3` where I can explitly tell what I did. When I install something with `apt-get` **and** add this `--change` line - then I would kinda double install something am I right? Isn't there a way to let docker *record* my changes and write them into the Dockerfile? Otherwise I have to decide whether I install something hidden or explictly to everybody can see it with `--change`

Comment: change is message so you need to manually record and there is no way to record the change. But one thing that can be done is compare the `~/.bash_history` between two layers. But that will only give you what commands were executed through bash. If you installed a jenkins plugin through its GUI then those changes can't be recorded anywhere

Comment: So I have to unmount jenkins container volumes and reinstall all plugins? Then it will be recorded? Is there not explicit way to tell docker to commit volumes as well?

Comment: As of now there is none. Also you can customize the jenkins image using Dockerfile and directly specify plugins. See this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255277/how-do-i-add-plugins-to-a-docker-jenkins/46261232#46261232